# ember hasDirtyAttributes do not work with object (json)

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a model:

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  attributes: attr('jsonb')
});
```

Where `attributes` is a custom `json` filed stored as `jsonb` in Postgres.

let say:

```
{
"name":"Bob",
"city":""
}
```

So I can easily manipulate `attributes`  using template
`<form.element .. @property="attributes.city"/>` or `model.set('attributes.city','city name')`

**Problem**: `hasDirtyAttributes` do not changing because technically we have old object. But when I try to copy object let say
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.get('attributes'))` `hasDirtyAttributes` works as expected

So how to write some `Mixin` for a `Model` or other workaround which on the change of any `attribute` property will mark `hasDirtyAttributes` as `true`. I will update whole object so doesn't matter which property actually was changed.

Same problem: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/hasdirtyattributes-do-not-work-with-nested-attributes-json-api/15592

existing solution doesn't work for me at all:

- ember-dirtier
- ember-data-relationship-tracker
- ember-data-model-fragments (a lot of changes under the hood and broke my app)

**Update:**

---

Some not perfect idea that help better describe what I'm want to achieve:
Let say we adding observer to any object `fileds`:

```
export default Model.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();

    this.set('_attributes', Object.assign({}, this.get('attributes'))); //copy original 
    Object.keys(this.get('attributes')).forEach((item) => {
      this.addObserver('attributes.'+ item, this, this.objectObserver);
    });
  }
...
})
```

And observer:

```
objectObserver: function(model, filed){
    let privateFiled = '_' + filed;

    if (model.get(privateFiled) != model.get(filed)) { //compare with last state
      model.set(privateFiled, this.get(filed));
      model.set('attributes', Object.assign({}, this.get('attributes')) );
    }

  }
```

It's works, but when I change one `filed` in `object` due to copying object `objectObserver` faired again on every filed. So in this key changing every `filed` in `object` I mark observed filed as `dirty`

Answer (score 0):

The further `ember` development will reduce using of event listener and two-way binding, actually Glimmer components supports only `One-way Data Flow`. So to be friendly with future versions of `ember`using one-way data flow is good approach in this case to. So In my case as I use `ember boostrap` solution looks like

```
<form.element @controlType="textarea" @onChange={{action 'attributeChange'}}
```

where `attributeChange` action do all works.

New Glimmer / Octane style based on `modifier` and  looks like:

```
{{!-- templates/components/child.hbs --}}
<button type="button" {{on "click" (fn @onClick 'Hello, moon!')}}>
  Change value
</button>
```